# Append input text to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, input

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="edit-submitted-telefon" name="submitted[telefon]" step="any" class="form-text form-number required">
```

In default, it has no value. But I want use cookie, so it must have a value and the value about users text.

For exmaple, when user write LOREM IPSUM to this input, be like this:

```
<input type="text" id="edit-submitted-telefon" name="submitted[telefon]" step="any" class="form-text form-number required" value='LOREM IPSUM'>
```

---

EDIT: I used this code but it don't work.

```
   $('#edit-submitted-telefon').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function() {
      $('#edit-submitted-telefon').val(this.value);
      console.log($('#edit-submitted-telefon').val());
    });
```

---

After, working cookie code and it works.

```
$(".webform-submit").click(function () {
        $.cookie('telCookie', $el1.val(), {
          expires: 365
        });
      });

      //set the value of the cookie to the element element_1
      var $el1 = $("#edit-submitted-telefon").val($.cookie("telCookie"))
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this code:

```
$('#edit-submitted-telefon').bind('keydown keyup keypress', function() {
  $('#edit-submitted-telefon').val(this.value);
  console.log($('#edit-submitted-telefon').val());
});
```

The element takes the value automatically

I think you only need to do something like this:

```
$(function(){  //document ready
    $("#edit-submitted-telefon").val($.cookie("telCookie")); //load the value from cookie

    $(".webform-submit").click(function () {
        $.cookie('telCookie', $('#edit-submitted-telefon').val(), {
          expires: 365
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not working. When I checked devtools, not found any error or something... input has no value.

Comment: The first time there is no value

Comment: But when I back the form, still has no value.

Comment: Are you using document ready? Take a look at this Q&A about cookies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: Yes, I'm using document ready. Everything looks fine. I think, I have problem about input value.

Comment: .webform-submit element has type="submit"? You can try removing type="submit" and submitting the form after setting telCookie value with $('form').submit();

Comment: My submit input: <input class="webform-submit button-primary form-submit" type="submit" name="op" value="GÖNDER">

Comment: Try setting type="button" and submitting your form using javascript